# Low-level GPIO port in Linux (raspberry, banana)

Tags: c++, linux, gpio

i try to change GPIO data in the processor (not using wiringPI library)

```
int fd = open ("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC);
unsigned long* gpio1 = (unsigned long *)mmap(NULL, 8*1024, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0x01C20000);
*(gpio1 + 0x800) = 0x31111111; // (for example)
```

When i read memory again the changing data is lost

Comment: Re, "When i read memory again the changing data is lost."  You haven't shown us that part of the code (i.e., the part that reads memory again, and then does something wrong because of what it read).  Show us a program that does something you didn't expect it to do, and tell us what it actually did do instead.

Comment: I don't know the Raspberry PI, but if the address `gpio1+0x800` is a memory mapped device register, then there is no reason why you should expect to be able to read back what you wrote to it.  Sometimes you can, sometimes you can't.  Depends on how the device is implemented.  You should consult the data sheets and/or reference manual for whatever the device is.

Comment: This Q  **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related site http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ . Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I worked with the banana pro board and i think i did something wrong, bacause i test this example http://elinux.org/RPi_GPIO_Code_Samples 
on raspberry, and it`s works!